# Way to use OpenSAML in C#

Tags: c#, opensaml

[OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home/) is using JAVA, is there any way of using this in C#,

i have try to using http://www.ikvm.net/download.html to convert JAVA to .dll but alot file is not found when convert.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to specifcally use OpenSAML, over any other implementation of SAML?

Comment: because i want same generate encryption result same as openSAML

Comment: OpenSAML uses standard encryptions so there is really no need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, SAML is a  data format for exchanging authentication and authorization data and used mostly in federated identity scenarios. And it's not a new format and has support in .NET environment.

I don't think you need to use java based implementation in .net, you at least can find something similar for .net or just use combination of WIF, WCF and ADSF (or some of them).

You can find a bit more information here : [Claims-based auth with WIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335707.aspx) and here [SAML based claims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733083.aspx).

There is also very good free book from MS patterns & practices about Claims-Based Identity and Access Control [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx).

Comment: Is it will generate same result encryption as openSAML?

Comment: Could you please explain, that do you mean "...same encryption results..."?

Comment: Mean if i using OpenSAML perform the key encryption is it will same with other SAML encryption, because other company provide openSAML(which using java, C++) but i require to use C#

Comment: If you just use the same encrytion scheme you will get the same result. You can find which is used in the SAML metadata.

Answer (score 3):

My knowledge of C# is quite fuzzy, but as I understand using a C++ library in C# is a piece of cake. And if this is true your in luck.

As you can see in the OpenSAML 2 box on [this page](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home) there is a C++ version of the library.

As a comment there is a lot of other products out there that probably can be used instead. OpenSAML is a low level library for SAML and using it securely involves a lot of manual labour and knowledge.